# Entering in the admin portal of Liferay 6.1

Tags: tomcat, liferay, admin, portal

Hullo all,

I have a fresh installation of Liferay 6.1 with Tomcat 7, and I need to enter in the admin portal.

The docs say "test@liferay.com" with password "test". Apparently these have long been "bruno@7cogs.com" and "bruno".

Nothing works.

Does someone have the sesame ?

Thank you.

Nicolas

Comment: Can you post the result of Select * from User_ against your database?

Comment: How do I do that ?

Nobody has changed the database settings of this installation yet. If I have understood correctly, the database is the mini-database Hypersonic of Liferay.

Answer (score 2):

For Liferay, after the installation is done, you would need to register with a username and password as the admin user. In fact, the very first user that you would register would become the admin user and after that you can add as many users as you want and you can set different access levels to the new user(s).

Comment: Thank you Uresh ! I have done that, and now at least I can enter. The user I have created has the roles "User" and "Power User", but no "Admin" role, and I have not found any way to add such a role. I think this is needed, I will need to deploy and manage Portlets in the Portal. Cheers, Nicolas

Comment: I don't find how to create other users. Any clue ?

Comment: Try this: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen12-adding-users-0